# Работа с коллекциями (Java)

Tags: java, функции, коллекции

Дали задание: реализовать функцию, которая вернет список элементов первого списка, которых нет во втором списке (в порядке появления в первом списке). Реализовать функцию `indexOf`, которую использовать в реализации функции `inList1NotInList2`.

Ошибку пишет, что возвращаемое значение `=` `null`. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку.

```java
public static int indexOf(List<Integer> list, int value) {
    int index = list.indexOf(value);
    return index;
}

public int inList1NotInList2(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        if (list1.get(i) == list2.get(i)) {
            list3.add(count, indexOf(list1, list2.get(i)));
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: У вас функция inList1NotInList2 возвращает int и возвращаете, как я понимаю, количество элементов добавленных в list3. По заданию вы хотите получить список. Так и должно быть? И мне не совсем понятно что за переменная list3. В ней так же может быть ошибка.

Comment: Функция inList1NotinList2 - да, возвращает количество элементов. list3 - это список который показывает конечный результат

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут же сразу понятно, что первый список длинный, а второй короткий. Цикл перебора идёт по длинному списку, и когда длинный список ещё не закончился , а короткий закончился то list2.get(i) вызовет ошибку, потому что там ничего нет по условию задачи.

Comment: List1 и List2 равны по условию задачи, и может здесь я не скинул код, но они равны. Либо я не понимаю, что вы хотите сказать